# How can I check if uploaded and downloaded file have same content with cypress?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-file-upload

I wanted to test if the content of the uploaded file and the downloaded file are the same. So, following is what I tried through cypress:

```
it.only(cfg.testname, () => {

    // 1. Login to website, navigate to desired webapge
    // 2. Upload the file
    // 3. Download the file

    // cy.wait(5000)
    
    // 4. Read the uploaded file:
    const fileContent = cy.fixture(_filePath)
    console.log('fixture file path', '======>', _filePath)
    console.log('fixture file content', '=====>', fileContent)
    
    // 5. Read the downloaded file:
    const downloadsFolder = Cypress.config("downloadsFolder")
    const downloadedFileContent = cy.readFile(path.join(downloadsFolder, _fileName))
    console.log('downloaded file path', '======>', path.join(downloadsFolder, fileName))
    console.log('downloaded file content','====>', downloadedFileContent)
    
    // 6. Check if they are equal:
    expect(downloadedFileContent).equals(fileContent)            
})
```

However, when I run this test, it does not even complete login step and immediately give asserition error one step 6, that is on `expect()...`:

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) } to equal { 
Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) }
    at Context.eval (VM753 tests:224)
```

When I comment step 6 `expect()...`, it correctly logins, uploads file and downloads file. So, I felt somehow I should make the process wait till download is complete before `expect()...`. So I tried uncommenting `cy.wait(5000)`, but no help. It still gives me above error (with of course `expect()...` uncommented).

**Q1.** Why this behavior?
**Q2.** How should I fix this?

PS: I am getting bunch of errors in the console which I am unable to understand. This is the screenshot of console:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixture read is async, so you need to use `.then()`, same with `cy.readFile()`

The use of `path.join(downloadsFolder, _fileName)` probably will not work as it's a Node command, substitute a string template instead

If you have a complicated file in JSON format, also try `.to.deep.eq`

```js
cy.fixture(_filePath).then(fileContent => {
  const downloadsFolder = Cypress.config("downloadsFolder")
  const downloadPath = `${downloadsFolder}/${_fileName}`
  cy.readFile(downloadPath).then(downloadedFileContent => { 
    expect(downloadedFileContent).equals(fileContent)   
    // or may need deep
    // expect(downloadedFileContent).to.deep.eq(fileContent)   
  })
})
```